# I am getting error "" when trying to generate an ERD image for my database models in django

Tags: python, django, graphviz, pydot

I have already set-up my database models and for the sake of visualizing my data's, I would like to generate a structure for it. I have installed the required packages which were successful.

List of installed packages for generating the graph using the pip command:

```
pydot
pyparsing
Graphviz
django-extensions
```

I was able to generate the dot file successfully by running the command `python manage.py graph_models -a > erd.dot` which worked successfully but whenever I used the command `python manage.py graph_models -a -g -o erd.png` in order to generate an image for it I get the `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot" not found in path` error.

Comment: Did you install graphviz(not the python package)? You need to install graphviz separately also the package simply uses the executable (might also need to add it to the PATH). You can download it on [https://graphviz.org/download/](https://graphviz.org/download/).

Comment: alright. Thanks. I will do that now

Comment: While pyparsing is part of this set of modules, it is not really relevant to the issue you are having. I'm editing your question to remove the `[pyparsing]` tag.

Answer (score -1):

After many tries and getting the same erros when trying to convert the .dot into a .png I just searched online and found several online tools that did this. I uploaded the .dot file but most of them gave me a PNG that did not have the tables and the lines as they should. This one converted correctly though: https://onlineconvertfree.com/convert/dot/

I also found a github project where you can paste the .dot code in, and it will provide a diagram on the side which can also be downloaded: [Link](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20G%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_0%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20style%3Dfilled%3B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3Dlightgrey%3B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bstyle%3Dfilled%2Ccolor%3Dwhite%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20a0%20-%3E%20a1%20-%3E%20a2%20-%3E%20a3%3B%0A%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22process%20%231%22%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20subgraph%20cluster_1%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bstyle%3Dfilled%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20b0%20-%3E%20b1%20-%3E%20b2%20-%3E%20b3%3B%0A%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22process%20%232%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20color%3Dblue%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20start%20-%3E%20a0%3B%0A%20%20start%20-%3E%20b0%3B%0A%20%20a1%20-%3E%20b3%3B%0A%20%20b2%20-%3E%20a3%3B%0A%20%20a3%20-%3E%20a0%3B%0A%20%20a3%20-%3E%20end%3B%0A%20%20b3%20-%3E%20end%3B%0A%0A%20%20start%20%5Bshape%3DMdiamond%5D%3B%0A%20%20end%20%5Bshape%3DMsquare%5D%3B%0A%7D) . However, the first link above gave me a better-looking diagram.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34016617)